# Why is my initial Time Machine backup becoming much larger than the data on the source disk?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I’m backing up my 2 TB internal SSD to an external 2 TB SSD drive. Time Machine estimates the backup to be 1.13 TB, so it should easily fit into the external drive.

[image: Backup estimate]

However, even the first backup doesn’t complete because the backup disk is full before the first backup finishes (only 1.3 GB left):

[image: Disk Utility]

Finder is not showing any backups:

[image: No backups shown]

I tried formatting the external disk, but the issue keeps occurring.

How can I find out what’s causing this?

OS version is macOS 11.6 (20G165).

Comment: Do you have an external drive connected? If yes - make sure you add it to the "Excluded" list.

Comment: No, the backup disk is the only external drive.

Comment: Maybe the answer here or some of the discussions might help in case you have not seen it: [Time Machine thinks the size of my backup is bigger than the source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405674)

Comment: Do you have a Dropbox, OneDrive, or GoogleDrive volume on this machine configured for offline access?  Time Machine isn't going to know how that works, and the client(s) are going to try to sync the local data as TM reads the files.  Exclude such directories.

Comment: @MarcWilson Yes, I actually have both Google Drive and Dropbox installed and configured for streaming. I’ll try excluding those directories and report back!

Comment: @MarcWilson Excluding the Dropbox folders (I have two of them because there are multiple user accounts on my machine) did the trick. Google Drive was actually excluded by default (it’s not visible in my screenshot above because I only use it on another account, but on that account it’s shown in light grey in the exclusion list). Feel free to post this as an answer, then I’m going to accept it! Many thanks!

Comment: @KevinGrabher It's well worth being aware of all external drives, and making sure you exclude them promptly. (A few months ago I set up a big external drive, and Time Machine deleted 3 years' worth of old backups to try to make room for it before I realised what was happening…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have a Dropbox, OneDrive, or GoogleDrive volume on this machine configured for offline/streaming access.

When Time Machine reaches those directories, it will read the files, and the client (Dropbox, Google Drive, whiatever) will respond by streaming the data, which Time Machine will write to the backup as though they were regular files.

If the on-line storage is large enough, Time Machine will overflow the backup medium while streaming the files.

Exclude such directories.